# Not possible to recover or delete file in a ext4 filesystem

Tags: filesystems, data-recovery, ext4

How can I fix a message like this (read after a `dmesg` command)?

```
EXT4-fs error (device hdb1): ext4_lookup: deleted inode referenced: 119197
EXT4-fs error (device hdb1): ext4_free_inode: bit already cleared for inode 119198
EXT4-fs error (device hdb1): ext4_lookup: deleted inode referenced: 119197
EXT4-fs error (device hdb1): ext4_free_inode: bit already cleared for inode 119217
EXT4-fs warning (device hdb1): ext4_unlink: Deleting nonexistent file (119196), 0
EXT4-fs error (device hdb1): ext4_free_inode: bit already cleared for inode 119201
EXT4-fs error (device hdb1): ext4_lookup: deleted inode referenced: 119197
EXT4-fs error (device hdb1): ext4_lookup: deleted inode referenced: 119197
EXT4-fs error (device hdb1): ext4_lookup: deleted inode referenced: 119197
EXT4-fs error (device hdb1): ext4_lookup: deleted inode referenced: 119197
EXT4-fs error (device hdb1): ext4_lookup: deleted inode referenced: 119197
EXT4-fs error (device hdb1): ext4_lookup: deleted inode referenced: 119197
```

It seems impossible to retrieve (or delete) a bunch of files. Any suggestions?

Comment: and the file is not recoverable    example.MYI: Input/output error

Comment: Clone whatever data you have left with Clonezilla to another disk

Comment: backup your data ( assuming that you still can) and run a fsck on the disk.

Answer (score 2):

The EXT4 filesystem's data structures are corrupted.  You need to unmount the filesystem and run fsck on it. Assuming the disk itself is sound, fsck should be able to correct these problems. Run `fsck -y /dev/hdb1`, then restore anything you're concerned about from backups.

Comment: the fsck utility start booting time ( when my system re start). The problem is recovery the data corrupted without use ( or before use ) some like fsck or e2fsck