# Ext4-Error: Bit already cleared for inode

Tags: debian, ext4, sd-card, journaling

System:

- Debian Wheezy Kernel 3.11.6
- Atmel SAM9x25
- Mono 3.2.8
- SD card with ext4 partition

I got following message error when I booted my mono application:

```
root@net-231:/opt/programm# [ 6061.078125] EXT4-fs error (device 

mmcblk0p2): ext4_free_inode:319: comm rm: bit already cleared for inode 48113
[ 6067.031250] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p2): mb_free_blocks:1426: group 0, block 8307:freeing already freed block (bit 8307)
[ 6067.039062] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p2): ext4_mb_generate_buddy:755: group 0, 9355 clusters in bitmap, 9356 in gd
```

Questions:

- What does that error mean exactly?
- What can cause such an error?
- Is it possible to automatically fix such errors?

Comment: Already discussed here : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83395/not-possible-to-recover-or-delete-file-in-a-ext4-filesystem .

Comment: But it doesnt answer how it can be caused.